# How to increment two variables in r using if statements?

Tags: r, if-statement, increment

I generated a 600 length sample using:

```
x <- rnorm(600, mean = 30, sd = 10)
```

and then made another 600 length list using:

```
y = ((x-30)/10)
```

and my plan is to have if statements that test whether y is bigger than 1.96 and if `-y` is smaller than 1.96 and if this happens then increment a variable `a` by 1 and if this doesn't happen then increment a variable `b` by 1.

I have tried the following things:

```
a = 0
b = 0

ifelse(y > 1.96, inc(a) <- 1, inc(b) <- 1)
ifelse(-y < -1.96, inc(a) <- 1, inc(b) <- 1)
```

> Error in inc(a) <- 1 : could not find function "inc<-"
>   Error in inc(b) <- 1 : could not find function "inc<-"

```
ifelse(y > 1.96, '+'(a) <- 1, '+'(b) <- 1)
ifelse(-y < -1.96, '+'(a) <- 1, '+'(b) <- 1)
```

> Error in +a <- 1 : could not find function "+<-"
>   Error in +b <- 1 : could not find function "+<-"

```
if (y > 1.96) {
  a = a + 1
}
if (-y < -1.96) {
  a = a + 1
} else{
  b = b + 1
}
```

> Warning message:
>     In if (y > 1.96) { :
>         the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

```
ifelse(y > 1.96, a <- a + 1, b <- b + 1)
ifelse(-y < -1.96, a <- a + 1, b <- b + 1)
```

This almost worked but it gave me an output of all 1's and:

```
  a
  # [1] 1
  b
  # [1] 1
```

So how else would I increment the variables or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if y > 1.96 then -y must be <-1.96. R is vectorised so sum(y>1.96) etc will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid using an `ifelse()` for this kind of computation. In this case, it's better to use R's vectorization properties (e.g. there is no "scalar" in R only vectors) by obtaining a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values and then sum over the `TRUE` values.

```
# Make the data
set.seed(1337)
x = rnorm(600, mean = 30, sd = 10) 

y = ((x-30)/10)

# Get Indicators (T/F)
v1 = y > 1.96

v2 = y < -1.96

# Sum over w.r.t to true cases
a = sum(v1) + sum(v2)

# Handle the false cases without resumming. 
b = 2*length(y) - a
```

Also, here we opt to use `y < -1.96` to get an appropriate two-side count.